# Whats the best way to submit a dynamic form in Rails with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

In my appliacation I am managing many Workflows which contain many Variables. 
- Each Variable has its own value. 
- Every workflow is associated with 1 or more variables.

I have a workflow configuration page in which the user will select a workflow and then be presented with its associated variables to enter values. The problem I am having is coming up with the best way to save the entries on the form from the user. Usually I would do an ajax call to something like /variables/:id/update but in this case I want to update multiple variables at the same time when the save button is pressed. My thought was to create a custom method in the variables controller to handle this, but in that attempt I get an error about Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get. I feel there there is probably a much better way of doing this, but I'm a bit green and just dont know. Anyone have a suggestion?

My Form in customize.html.erb looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-10" style="background-color:yellow; height: 216px; ">
    <div class="h3">Required ContextDataDef Values:</div>
      <div class="workflow_variables">           
          <div id="placeholder"></div>                             
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript looks like:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.list-group .workflow-item', function() {
    var listGroupItem$ = $(this).find('.list-group-item');
    var listGroupItemName = listGroupItem$.text();

    var workflowId$ = $(this).find('.workflow-id-string');
    var workflowIdText = workflowId$.text();


    $.getJSON('/workflows/'+ workflowIdText + '/details', function(foundFlow) {
      console.log(foundFlow);

    var flowName = foundFlow['name'];
    var flowDescrip = foundFlow['description'];

    $('#flowName').val(flowName);
    $('#flowDescrip').val(flowDescrip);
    });


    $.getJSON('/workflows/'+ workflowIdText + '/getFlowVariables', function(foundVars) {
    console.log(foundVars);

    var output="";
    for (var i in foundVars) {
        output+=" <form class='form-inline' id='variableValuesForm' data-remote='true'>" +  "<label for='@variable' style='margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 5px;'>" + foundVars[i].name + ":</label>" + "<input type='text' style='width: 170px; margin-top: 5px;' class='text small' name=" + foundVars[i].name + " id=" + foundVars[i].name + " value=" + foundVars[i].value + ">" + "<input type='text' style='width: 20px; margin-top: 5px;' class='text small' name='varID' id='varID' value=" + foundVars[i].id + ">" + "<button>Save</button>" + "</form>";
    }
    output+="";

    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;


    });


  });
```

----  UPDATE ----
Based on the comments, I've updated the info above:

So when I add the data-remote=true, what I end up getting is this

```
 Started GET "/clients/4/customize?&rbYouTubeUsername=MyUser&varID=29"
```

This is nice and all, but I really want to call a different method than customize. What I want to get is something like:

```
 Started GET "/clients/4/updateVariable?&rbYouTubeUsername=MyUser&varID=29"
```

Or in a perfect world I would get this:

```
 Started GET "/variable/29/update?&rbYouTubeUsername=MyUser"
```

Comment: rails already has built in support for ajax in forms, you can check here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: This doesnt really help. I am aware of the rails form helpers, but not how they can be used when the form doesnt exist yet when the page is first loaded. The Form will only exist when the user clicks on the workflow to trigger the form to become visible. Its the fact that it doesnt always exist that leads to the complexity of the issue..

Comment: Mohammad is correct. You want to use Rails' idea of unobtrusive javascript. Even if you don't use the form helpers on the Ruby side, you can still add data-remote="true" to get the effects you want.

Comment: So when I add the data-remote=true, what I end up getting is this
     Started GET "/clients/4/customize?&rbYouTubeUsername=MyUser&varID=29"

This is nice and all, but I really want to call a different method than customize.  What I want to get is something like:

Started GET "/clients/4/updateVariable?&rbYouTubeUsername=MyUser&varID=29"

Or in a perfect world I would get this:

Started GET "/variable/29/update?&rbYouTubeUsername=MyUser"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key elements I was missing was having a clear understanding of adding the data-remote='true' parameter along with an action parameter so I could control what method of the controller to send the form data to. Once I added both of these elements to the form, it all makes sense.

```
 data-remote='true' action='update_variable'
```

Now the result is

```
 Started GET "/clients/4/update_variable?rbYouTubeUsername=AnotherNewVal&varID=29"
```